Can someone explain when a limit is defined?
Why is it that the following limit is defined if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$?
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
In contrast, the limit isn't defined if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \neq 0$ but $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$. Why this discrepancy?
Using the epsilon delta definition, I can prove the following:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}\;\text{provided that}\;\lim_{x\to a}g(x) \neq 0$$
I can also prove the following:
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \cdot h(x) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a}h(x)$$
Therefore , taking $h(x) = 1/g(x)$ :
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}\left[f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{g(x)}\right] = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{g(x)}$$
Now, provided that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) \neq 0$, we can deduce/evaluate the following:
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$$
So how come this limit is defined if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$ provided that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = 0$? This doesn't make any sense to me.

You can imagine comparing their ‘’velocity’‘ as they approach $0$.

@BoweiTang yes I have somewhat of an intuition. But I'm asking for a proof. Why is $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ defined in some cases when the numerator's limit is also zero but not in other cases when the numerator's limit isn't zero?

Have you learned Taylor's expansion? That works.

That first statement is not true. The limit is sometimes defined and sometimes isn't. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form for details.

@QiaochuYuan thanks that clarifies some doubts. However, I still wonder why 0/0 is categorized as an indeterminate form but not x/0 where $x\neq 0$? Can we be 100% sure that $lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is undefined if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\neq 0$? Why?

“Indeterminate” is somewhat an arbitrary terminology; the limit (or the existence of the limit) of the quotient is not known only because we haven’t figured it out. By the same token it’s perfectly logical to call every limit an indeterminate before we have solved it. But for whatever reason, it’s just not the common terminology. All in all, the categorization is arbitrary, so there’s no real reason why a/0 is not classified as indeterminate but 0/0 is.

Why is $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ defined in some cases when the numerator's limit is also zero but not in other cases $[\ldots]$ --- This is NOT what your first sentence says, and your first sentence is NOT true: @Qiaochu Yuan comment. You should edit your question so that what you say/write is what you intend. Maybe only need to change “limit is defined” to “limit sometimes exists”. (I’ve replaced “is defined” with “exists”, since “define” causes a slightly greater reading/parsing task on the reader due to it’s other mathematical meaning as “accepted without necessity of proof”.)

You can have all possibilities by taking $g(x)=f(x)^2,$ $f(x)=g(x)^2$ or $f(x)=cg(x)$ for a constant $c.$

The problem with $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, when $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$ is that the expression $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ can obtain aribitrarily large values, which means that if the first limit exists (because in some cases it can exist), it cannot be finite and is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.
The proof
Consider $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, such that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists, is finite and not equal to $0$, and $\lim_{x \to a } g(x) = 0$, but there is some neighbourhood of $a$ such that $g(x) \neq 0$ in that neighbourhood. Therefore we have $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = A$ for some $A > 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a } |g(x)| = 0$
This means that, we can choose some $\delta_1$, such that:
$$|x-a| < \delta_1 \implies ||f(x)| - A| < A \implies |f(x)| > 0$$
For arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ we can choose $\delta_2$, such that:
$$|x-a| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x)| < \varepsilon \implies \frac{1}{|g(x)|} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
Now taking $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$:
$$|x-a| < \delta \implies \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$$
but $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ can be any positive real number, so the expression $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ can be arbitrarily large.

The examples
Here are $3$ examples of functions of mentioned form with different limit behaviours:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{-x^2} = -\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \quad \text{Does not exist}$$
